# SVG background is not working in Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari

I'm attempting to use an svg as a background. The svg has multiple icons within it so I want to be able to have a full size height of the background and choose the icon based on the background position. Doing so is fine in Chrome, but I can't seem to get the svg to work at all in Safari.

https://codepen.io/matthew-ableengine/pen/BwbBmp

Here is a codepen of my attempt.

The css I'm using is

```
.test{
  background: url('http://svgshare.com/i/3WD.svg');
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-position-x: 100px;
}
```

and my SVG is http://svgshare.com/i/3WD.svg

Comment: It just works fine in safari on my computer (safari 10.1), what did you already tried?

Comment: I'm using safari 9.1 and I just see a blank screen

Comment: I have tested in 7. got the same result, looks like the offset doesn't work with a svg. Maybe adding a gradient in the background of the svg can help you to give a clue what you are looking at. Try using another preserveAspectRatio value, unfortunately I can't help you much further.